# Can't find PrismaClient when setup as TurboRepo package

Tags: node.js, npm, prisma, turborepo

I'm trying to setup Prisma as a seperate package within my TurboRepo following the instructions here: https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/prisma.

I have a `server` folder setup with some basic NodeJS Azure Functions where I'm trying to use it.

My issue is when attemping to run the functions it is unable to find the PrismaClient.

I can see that my `database` package is present in the `dist` of my server when it is being run.

However, the index.js file is empty and I'm unsure on what is configured incorrectly that is preventing TurboRepo from transpiling my TS code.

In my `database` folder I have...

An `index.ts` file:

```
export * from '@prisma/client';
```

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "database",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "./index.ts",
  "types": "./index.ts",
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run prisma:generate && mkdir -p node_modules && cp -R ../../node_modules/.prisma node_modules/.prisma",
    "build": "tsc",
    "lint": "prisma validate",
    "prisma:studio": "prisma studio",
    "prisma:generate": "prisma generate",
    "prisma:push": "prisma db push --skip-generate",
    "prisma:seed": "prisma db seed",
    "prisma:deploy": "prisma migrate deploy"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mermaid-js/mermaid-cli": "^9.2.2",
    "prisma": "^4.6.1",
    "prisma-erd-generator": "^1.2.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.6.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  }
```

In my server I have the following code to instantiate the PrismaClient:

```
// /repository/index.ts
import { PrismaClient } from 'database';

const prismaClient = new PrismaClient();
export default prismaClient;
```

Which compiles to:

```js
// /dist/repository/index.js

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const database_1 = require("database");
const prismaClient = new database_1.PrismaClient();
exports.default = prismaClient;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

This file references my `database` package. However, this package is empty.

[image: Empty index.js]

As can be seen in my `database/package.json` I have experimented with manually adding in build steps to build the database package however this has not made a difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Have you specified a custom output for PrismaClient?
https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#specify-a-custom-output-location-for-prisma-client

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared packages/database into your dependency where you're using prisma

```
client?
"dependencies": {
 "database": "workspace:*"
}
```

This doc demonstrates how to set it up properly
https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/tools/prisma